GitHub Copilot v1.221.0: FetchError ETIMEDOUT in VS Code
I'm encountering an issue with GitHub Copilot in Visual Studio Code, where the extension is unable to send telemetry data. The error log shows FetchError: ETIMEDOUT. This occurs every time I try to use Copilot, and it's preventing me from fully utilizing the tool.
Error Log:
2024-08-09 14:38:13.961 [info] [fetcher] Using Helix fetcher.
2024-08-09 14:38:13.961 [info] [code-referencing] Public code references are enabled.
2024-08-09 14:38:14.010 [info] [auth] Successfully authenticated
2024-08-09 14:38:16.964 [error] [default] Error sending telemetry FetchError: 
    at fetch (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\github.copilot-1.221.0\node_modules\@adobe\helix-fetch\src\fetch\index.js:99:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at cachingFetch (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\github.copilot-1.221.0\node_modules\@adobe\helix-fetch\src\fetch\index.js:288:16)
    at OO.fetch (c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\github.copilot-1.221.0\lib\src\network\helix.ts:96:22) {
  type: 'system',
  _name: 'FetchError',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: undefined,
  erroredSysCall: undefined
}


VS Code version:1.92.1
GitHub Copilot version: v1.221.0
OS:WINDOWS 11
Are there any workarounds or fixes?
What I've Tried:
Restarting VS Code
Reinstalling the Copilot extension
Checking network connectivity
Environment:

ETIMEDOUT is often a network error, so this might happen if your network is terrible. There's a likelihood it went away on its own, but if not, using things like a VPN, or unstable internet may cause that. You could check your internet connection by pinging a site if you're unsure.

There are proxy settings inside vs code. Put in your organizations' proxy server addresses in there, it worked for me

I had similar issue but with CERT_SIGNATURE_FAILURE error reported.
From what I noticed Copilot Chat extension still worked but it used 'Electron Fetcher' instead of 'Helix Fetcher'. So here you are solution that is working for me:
Open file: ~\.vscode\extensions\github.copilot-1.250.0\dist\extension.js
Replace all:
currentFetcher=this.helixFetcher with currentFetcher=this.electronFetcher
It was 4 occurences in my case.
